# Need help identifying this!

Tags: character-identification, seal

I received this awhile back and can't find any information.. please help with the signature and stamp

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "signature" is two Chinese characters, '**亜农**'.

The first (top) character is unclear, it should be '**亜**'

> 亜 (yà) = which means 'Asian' or 'second'

The second (bottom) character is '**农**'

> 农 (nóng) = which means 'agriculture' or 'farmer'

---

The red stamp word is '**林**', a character in a form of Seal script (篆体) which is an ancient style of writing Chinese characters.

> 林 (lín) = which means 'forest' or 'wood'

But here the character '**林**' may only means the author surname or we called as family name.

Comment: Could it be 亞娘？

Comment: It may be since it's just the author's name.